# placing text on the bottom of an element

Tags: css

I have a div with text inside it

```
<div>
    FC
</div>
```

for example that div is 100px wide and 200px tall 
is there any way to make the text sit on the bottom of the div

```
_____________
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|__FC_______|
```

the reson i want this is because i have a bar on a website i'm working on to improve my css, the bar sits at the top of the page inside that bar there's 1img with a float left and 2divs with a float right, the one with the fc sits to the left of the 2 on the right

```
________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                      |
| logoimg                                               div2(fc)  div1 |
|______________________________________________________________________|
```

I want the FC to sit on the bottom of the div, the bar isn't fixed, i used percentages with a min-height so i can't just give it a margin-top or i could by giving it a percentage however i want that fc to always sit on the exact bottom of where it is placed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the text in a span and set the `bottom` to 0, which refers to the y position of the element in it's location. It will glue to the bottom of the parent div. Remember that the parent div must be `relative` and the child must be `absolute` in order for this to work.

```css
.parentdiv
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  bottom: 0; position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentdiv">
    <span class="child">FC</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Er... That's not margin!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have it inside an element for sure. You can use `position: relative` on the parent and give `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` on the element. Example:

```css
.parent {position: relative; border: 1px solid #999; height: 200px;}
.parent .elem {position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 35%; width: 30%; border: 1px solid #99f;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="elem">FC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with **flexbox**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j707y3sL/1/)**

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: white;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

a {
  padding: 0 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .fc {
    order: 2;
  }  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="left">
    <a href="">Left</a>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
     <a class="fc" href="">FC Right 1</a>
     <a href="">Right 2</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you didn't understand the problem but thank you for that, interesting function that might help

Comment: If you are creating something like navbar i would avoid using position relative/absolute because you will have problem with responsiveness..

Comment: I updated my answer FC is at bottom when you resize to `<480px`, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pajxLngr/

HTML:

```
<div class="menuBar">
  <div class="imgLogo">logo</div>
  <div class="last">last</div>
  <div class="textOnBottom"><span>FC</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuBar {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 24px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  }
.imgLogo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}
.last {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}
.textOnBottom{
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.textOnBottom span {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```